# C: Time-efficient way to get value of second column in text file

Tags: c, parsing, text-files

I am parsing a simple text file with two columns in C.

The two columns are separated by a tab. While I need the whole line in a later stage I also have to extract the value in the second column.

My implementation of this part is so far (reading a gzipped file):

```
while (! gzeof(fp)) {

   // here I keep the whole line since I need it later (can I do this also faster?)
   strcpy(line_save, line);

   // get the value in the second column (first removing the newline char.):
   line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
   linkage = strtok(line,"\t");
   linkage = strtok(NULL,"\t"); // here I have the value in the second col. as the result

   // do stuff

   gzgets(fp, line, LL);
}
```

What is a more time-efficient way to do this?

I am reading a gzipped file. `gzeof()` checks if EOF is reached and `gzgets()` reads one line.

I am not looking for an overly advanced solution here, but I am interested mainly in the "low-hanging fruits". However, if you can present more advances solutions I do not mind.

Comment: The time to find a column will be dominated by the time it takes to read the file.

Comment: @interjay OK, thanks for pointing this out. What might be a solution here? Ramdisk?

Comment: What are `gzeof()` and `gzgets()`?

Comment: @Zakk Check EOF for (gzeof) and read (gzgets) a gzipped file

Comment: As an obvious improvement you could remove the `\n` after splitting the line. `strcspn` has to walk all along the string from the beginning. Chopping the first part makes that walk shorter.

Comment: I wold assume using `while (!gzeof())` is wrong in the same way as [`while (!feof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: @Michael Why don't you unzip the file first?

Comment: @Zakk I wanted to simplify my workflow and keep the gzipped files. You mean unzip outside of the c-code before calling or within?

Comment: @Michael I mean either outside your code or within.

Comment: Do you have more than 2 columns? If yes, you don't need to remove the `\n` at all as it will be chopped by the second `strtok` anyway. If no, you might not need the second `strtok`

Comment: @Gerhardh I have exactly two columns.

Comment: Why not doing your own loop through the string. In the one loop you can copy the string, find both tabulators '\t' and extract your field. Or, at least you shall use more basic (character based) functions, like strchr instead of more general string based strcspn and strtok, considering you only used them with 1 character strings.

Comment: How often does the text file change? More specifically; can you do some kind of "if (original text file's modification time is newer than a pre-converted and cached binary file} { regenerate and cache the binary file}` followed by just using `mmap()` without any of the overhead of decompression or parsing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `gzgets()` [behaves](https://zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) in a similar way to `fgets()`:

> `ZEXTERN char * ZEXPORT gzgets OF((gzFile file, char *buf, int len));`
>
> Reads bytes from the compressed file until `len-1` characters are read, or a newline character is read and transferred to `buf`, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. If any characters are read or if `len == 1`, the string is terminated with a null character. If no characters are read due to an end-of-file or `len < 1`, then the buffer is left untouched.
>
> `gzgets` returns `buf` which is a null-terminated string, or it returns `NULL` for end-of-file or in case of error. If there was an error, the contents at `buf` are indeterminate.

```c
char line[128]; // Extend as you see fit
while (gzgets(gzfile, line, sizeof(line))) {
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    char col1[64], col2[64];
    if (sscanf(line, " %63s\t%63[^\n]", col1, col2) != 2) {
        // Error while parsing the line
        puts("Error");
    }
    
    // Testing
    printf("col1: '%s'\ncol2: '%s'\n", col1, col2);
    
    // And line is untouched.
}
```

---

**Edit:** The below version should run slightly faster than the one above:

- Removed the call for `strcspn()`
- The for-loop stops when a `\t` is met, so this avoids scanning the entire string.

```c
char line[128]; // Extend as you see fit
while (gzgets(gzfile, line, sizeof(line))) {
    char col1[64], col2[64];
    for (char *p = line; *p != '\0' && *p != '\n'; ++p) {
        if (*p == '\t') {
            strncpy(col1, line, p - line);
            strcpy(col2, p+1);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Testing
    printf("col1: '%s'\ncol2: '%s'\n", col1, col2);
    
    // And line is untouched.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So is this code assuming fixed length of col1 & col2 or not?

Comment: @Michael No, it isn't. The code assumes a **maximum** length of `col1` and `col2`, that you can adjust depending on your needs.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Hmm... this is even slower for me as my initial solution.

Comment: @Michael You souldn't count `printf()` execution time into account.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. BTW, probably you do not need to create a copy of `line` in `line_save` as this code does not destruct original `line.` If this is the case you can break the inner loop after having set `t2`.

```
while (! gzeof(fp)) {
    int i, t1, t2;
    
    t1 = t2 = -1;
    for(i=0; line[i]!=0; i++) {
        line_save[i] = line[i];
        if (line[i] = '\t') {
            if (t1 < 0) t1 = i;
            else if (t2 < 0) t2 = i;
        }
    }
    line_save[i] = 0;

    if (t2 >= 0) {
        line[t2] = 0;
        linkage = &line[t1+1];
        // do what you need with 'linkage'

        // reconstruct the original line
        line[t2] = '\t';
    }

    // do other stuf with 'line'

    gzgets(fp, line, LL);
}
```